# FFMPEG changes pixel values when reading and saving png without modification

Tags: python, image, video, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

This is a toy problem that is the result of my trying to identify a bug within a video pipeline I'm working on. The idea is that I want to take a frame from a YUV420 video, modify it as an RGB24 image, and reinsert it. To do this I convert YUV420 -> YUV444 -> RGB -> YUV444 -> YUV420. Doing this without any modification should result in the same frame however I noticed slight color transformations.

I tried to isolate the problem using a toy 3x3 RGB32 png image. The function `read_and_save_image` reads the image and then saves it as new file. It returns the read pixel array. I run this function thrice successively using the output of the previous run as the input of the next. This is to demonstrate a perplexing fact. While passing an image through the function once causes the resulting image to have different pixel values, doing it twice does not change anything. Perhaps more confusing is that the pixel values returned by the function are all the same.

tldr; *How can I load and save the toy image below using ffmpeg as a new file such that the pixel values of the new and original files are identical?*

Here is the original image followed by the result from one and two passes through the function. Note that the pixel value displayed by when reading these images with Preview has changed ever so slightly. This becomes noticeable within a video.

*Test image (very small)* ->
[image: 3x3 test image file] <-

Here are the pixel values read (note that after being loaded and saved there is a change):

[original test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEk8Q.png)

[test image after one pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlkrF.png)

[test image after two passes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EvMw.png)

Edit: here is an RGB24 frame extracted from a video I am using to test my pipeline. I had the same issue with pixel values changing after loading and saving with ffmpeg.

[frame from video I was testing pipeline on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EnYy.png)

Here is a screenshot showing how the image is noticeably darker after ffmpeg. Same pixels on the top right corner of the image.

[image: zoomed in top right corner]

Here is the code of the toy problem:

```
import os
import ffmpeg
import numpy as np


def read_and_save_image(in_file, out_file, width, height, pix_fmt='rgb32'):
    input_data, _ = (
        ffmpeg
        .input(in_file)
        .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt=pix_fmt)
        .run(capture_stdout=True)
    )
  
    frame = np.frombuffer(input_data, np.uint8)
    print(in_file,'\n', frame.reshape((height,width,-1)))
    
    save_data = (
        ffmpeg
            .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt=pix_fmt, s='{}x{}'.format(width, height))
            .output(out_file, pix_fmt=pix_fmt)
            .overwrite_output()
            .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
    )
    
    

    save_data.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())
    save_data.stdin.close()
    #save_data.wait()

    return frame

try:
    test_img = "test_image.png"
    test_img_1 = "test_image_1.png"
    test_img_2 = "test_image_2.png"
    test_img_3 = "test_image_3.png"

    width, height, pix_fmt = 3,3,'rgb32'
    #width, height, pix_fmt = video_stream['width'], video_stream['height'],  'rgb24'
    test_img_pxls = read_and_save_image(test_img,test_img_1, width, height, pix_fmt)
    test_img_1_pxls = read_and_save_image(test_img_1,test_img_2, width, height, pix_fmt)
    test_img_2_pxls = read_and_save_image(test_img_2,test_img_3, width, height, pix_fmt)

    print(np.array_equiv(test_img_pxls, test_img_1_pxls))
    print(np.array_equiv(test_img_1_pxls, test_img_2_pxls))

except ffmpeg.Error as e:
    print('stdout:', e.stdout.decode('utf8'))
    print('stderr:', e.stderr.decode('utf8'))
    raise e


!mediainfo --Output=JSON --Full $test_img
!mediainfo --Output=JSON --Full $test_img_1
!mediainfo --Output=JSON --Full $test_img_2
```

Here is the console output of the program that shows that the pixel arrays read by ffmpeg are the same despite the images being different.

```
test_image.png 
 [[[253 218 249 255]
  [252 213 248 255]
  [251 200 244 255]]

 [[253 227 250 255]
  [249 209 236 255]
  [243 169 206 255]]

 [[253 235 251 255]
  [245 195 211 255]
  [226 103 125 255]]]
test_image_1.png 
 [[[253 218 249 255]
  [252 213 248 255]
  [251 200 244 255]]

 [[253 227 250 255]
  [249 209 236 255]
  [243 169 206 255]]

 [[253 235 251 255]
  [245 195 211 255]
  [226 103 125 255]]]
test_image_2.png 
 [[[253 218 249 255]
  [252 213 248 255]
  [251 200 244 255]]

 [[253 227 250 255]
  [249 209 236 255]
  [243 169 206 255]]

 [[253 235 251 255]
  [245 195 211 255]
  [226 103 125 255]]]
True
True
{
"media": {
"@ref": "test_image.png",
"track": [
{
"@type": "General",
"ImageCount": "1",
"FileExtension": "png",
"Format": "PNG",
"FileSize": "4105",
"StreamSize": "0",
"File_Modified_Date": "UTC 2023-01-19 13:49:00",
"File_Modified_Date_Local": "2023-01-19 13:49:00"
},
{
"@type": "Image",
"Format": "PNG",
"Format_Compression": "LZ77",
"Width": "3",
"Height": "3",
"BitDepth": "32",
"Compression_Mode": "Lossless",
"StreamSize": "4105"
}
]
}
}

{
"media": {
"@ref": "test_image_1.png",
"track": [
{
"@type": "General",
"ImageCount": "1",
"FileExtension": "png",
"Format": "PNG",
"FileSize": "128",
"StreamSize": "0",
"File_Modified_Date": "UTC 2023-01-24 15:31:58",
"File_Modified_Date_Local": "2023-01-24 15:31:58"
},
{
"@type": "Image",
"Format": "PNG",
"Format_Compression": "LZ77",
"Width": "3",
"Height": "3",
"BitDepth": "32",
"Compression_Mode": "Lossless",
"StreamSize": "128"
}
]
}
}

{
"media": {
"@ref": "test_image_2.png",
"track": [
{
"@type": "General",
"ImageCount": "1",
"FileExtension": "png",
"Format": "PNG",
"FileSize": "128",
"StreamSize": "0",
"File_Modified_Date": "UTC 2023-01-24 15:31:59",
"File_Modified_Date_Local": "2023-01-24 15:31:59"
},
{
"@type": "Image",
"Format": "PNG",
"Format_Compression": "LZ77",
"Width": "3",
"Height": "3",
"BitDepth": "32",
"Compression_Mode": "Lossless",
"StreamSize": "128"
}
]
}
}
```

Comment: Also if anybody has an idea as to why the original image (which I created by cropping a 3x3 square from a larger image) has a size of 4105 when it should only be 3x3x4x8=288 max (without LZ compression)? Note that the problem above also occurred when using other images.

Comment: 1) In the absence of color tags in the PNG, ffmpeg will use the BT601 color matrix to convert to RGB. That will make a difference.  2)The matrix conversion will result in fractional values, and these will be rounded for storage. That too can result in a difference while roundtripping.

Comment: If the image is already in RGB will the color matrix be used? I thought that it was for conversion to and from YUV. The toy problem above applies to both RGB32 and RGB24.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg prints a warning message `"Incompatible pixel format 'bgra' for codec 'png', auto-selecting format 'rgba'"`.
It means that even that we want FFmpeg to save the PNG image in `rgb32` pixels format, FFmpeg ignores the format, and save it as `rgba`.

---

It's not well documented, but `rgb32` data order is `b`,`g`,`r`,`a`,`b`,`g`,`r`,`a`... (when `a` = `255`).
It looks like the PNG pixel order applies `rgba`: `r`,`g`,`b`,`a`,`r`,`g`,`b`,`a`...

Even when setting the PNG pixel format to `rgb32`, the data is still stored in `rgba` pixel format (`r` color channel first).
When reading the PNG image the **red and the blue channels are swapped**.

---

Instead of using `rgb32`, we may use `bgr32` pixel format.
The data order of `bgr32` is the same as `rgba`.

I recommend you to use `rgba` or `rgb24` pixel formats, because they are native to PNG image format.

---

For testing I used the following code sample that compares all kind of combinations of `rgba`, `bgr32` and `rgb32`:

```
import os
import ffmpeg
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


def read_and_save_image(in_file, out_file, width, height, pix_fmt='rgb32'):
    input_data, _ = (
        ffmpeg
        .input(in_file)
        .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt=pix_fmt)
        .run(capture_stdout=True)
    )
  
    frame = np.frombuffer(input_data, np.uint8)
    print(in_file,'\n', frame.reshape((height,width,-1)))
    
    save_data = (
        ffmpeg
            .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt=pix_fmt, s='{}x{}'.format(width, height))
            .output(out_file, pix_fmt=pix_fmt)
            .overwrite_output()
            .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
    )
    
    save_data.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())
    save_data.stdin.close()
    #save_data.wait()

    #return frame
    return frame.reshape((height, width, -1))



img = np.array([[[253, 218, 249, 255],
  [252, 213, 248, 255],
  [251, 200, 244, 255]],
 [[253, 227, 250, 255],
  [249, 209, 236, 255],
  [243, 169, 206, 255]],
 [[253, 235, 251, 255],
  [245, 195, 211, 255],
  [226, 103, 125, 255]]], np.uint8)

test_img = "test_image.png"
test_img_1 = "test_image_1.png"

# Save img to binary file (file size is 3*3*4 = 36 bytes).
with open("test_image.bin", 'wb') as f:
    img.tofile(f)

#ffmpeg.input('test_image.bin', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgba', s='3x3').output(test_img, pix_fmt='rgba').overwrite_output().run()
ffmpeg.input('test_image.bin', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgba', s='3x3').output("rgba.bin", pix_fmt='rgba', format='rawvideo').overwrite_output().run()  # rgba
ffmpeg.input('test_image.bin', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgba', s='3x3').output("rgb32.bin", pix_fmt='rgb32', format='rawvideo').overwrite_output().run() # rgb32
ffmpeg.input('test_image.bin', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgba', s='3x3').output("bgr32.bin", pix_fmt='bgr32', format='rawvideo').overwrite_output().run() # bgr32
ffmpeg.input('test_image.bin', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgba', s='3x3').output(test_img, pix_fmt='rgba').overwrite_output().run() # PNG in rgba pixel format

png_img = np.array(Image.open(test_img)) # Read the input PNG image (use PIL for keeping the order r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a...)

rgba = np.fromfile("rgba.bin", dtype=np.uint8).reshape(3, 3, 4)
rgb32 = np.fromfile("rgb32.bin", dtype=np.uint8).reshape(3, 3, 4)
bgr32 = np.fromfile("bgr32.bin", dtype=np.uint8).reshape(3, 3, 4)

print(np.array_equiv(img, png_img))  # True
print(np.array_equiv(img, bgr32))  # True
print(np.array_equiv(img, rgb32))  # False

width, height, pix_fmt = 3, 3, 'bgr32' #'rgb32'
test_img_pxls = read_and_save_image(test_img, test_img_1, width, height, pix_fmt)

print(np.array_equiv(img, test_img_pxls))  # True
#print(np.array_equiv(test_img_pxls, test_img_1_pxls))
#print(np.array_equiv(test_img_1_pxls, test_img_2_pxls))

png_img1 = np.array(Image.open(test_img_1)) # Read test_img_1 PNG image (use PIL for keeping the order r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a...)
print(np.array_equiv(img, png_img1))  # True

ffmpeg.input('test_image.bin', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb32', s='3x3').output("test_image_rgb32.png", pix_fmt='rgb32').overwrite_output().run() # PNG in rgb32 pixel format
png_img_rgb32 = np.array(Image.open("test_image_rgb32.png")) # Read the input PNG image that stored as rgb32
print(np.array_equiv(img, png_img_rgb32))  # False
```

---

### Update:

Regardless `rgb32` issue, the differences are related to the [embedded color profile](https://ninedegreesbelow.com/photography/embedded-color-space-information.html) of the original test image (`test_image.png`).

The embedded color profile (and other [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) data), also explains the fact the the PNG file size is 4105 when the image data is much smaller.

- When opening the original image in image viewer that doesn't respect the color profile (like paint.net in Windows), the RGB values of the bottom right pixel are `[125, 103, 226]`.
- When opening the original image in image viewer that respects the color profile (like GIMP in Windows), the values are converted to `[129, 102, 234]`.

---

The following FFmpeg command converts `test_image.png` to raw format:

`ffmpeg -i test_image.png -pix_fmt rgba -f rawvideo test_image.bin`

FFmpeg conversion ignores the color profile (does not apply the color conversion as GIMP), and also removes the color profile.

Note:
The above command is equivalent to the following Python code:
`input_data, _ = ffmpeg.input(in_file).output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt=pix_fmt).run(capture_stdout=True)`

---

The following command converts `test_image.bin` back to PNG:

`ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s 3x3 -pixel_format rgba -i test_image.bin test_image_converted.png`

The new PNG image is without embedded color profile.

That explains the fact that after the first iteration, the pixels values stop changing (test_image_1.png = test_image_2.png = test_image_3.png).

---

When viewing the pixel values of test_image_converted.png in Windows, the values are the same as the values of the NumPy array in Python.
(Image with no color profile is assumed to comply [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) profile, and Windows nominal profile is sRGB).

When viewing the pixel values in Mac, the values may still look different (depends on the image viewer). In Mac the default color profile may not be sRGB, and the image viewer software may still apply color profile conversion.

Comment: This is not due to differing component layout.

Comment: @Gyan You are probably addressing the "YUV420 -> YUV444 -> RGB -> YUV444 -> YUV420" conversion. My answer applies the Python code sample where the only format used is `rgb32` and FFmpeg may use `rgba` (there are no conversions to YUV and from YUV).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't realize that ffmpeg did swapping like this and hadn't thought of using PIL! However this doesn't address the fact that the pixels have different absolute values. For example in the images that I posted the original pixel on the bottom left had an R value of 125 but the loaded and saved versions had a value of 121. Also, note that the issue still seems to occur when loading and saving an RGB24 image (with pixfmt = 'rgb24').

Comment: @walrus Can you please edit your post, and add the original PNG image? We want to make sure there is nothing odd about it.

Comment: @walrus Also, did you try my code sample? My code creates a new PNG image file named `test_image.png`. Are you getting the same issues with that PNG image?

Comment: The "test_image_rgb32.png" file output at the end still suffers from the same issue where all pixel values are slightly washed out. It's always by the same amount as I experienced, i.e. the bottom right pixel R value goes from 125 -> 121.

Also worth noting that the toy problem didn't have issues with color components being swapped so I don't think this is the cause...

Comment: I guess it's a Mac related issue. The issue is not reproducible in Windows. Could it be that the viewer you are using modifies the values? Is there an option to show the values as sRGB? When using PIL to read the image, are the values equals the original values, or equals the "modified values - shown by the viewer"?

Comment: Note: The file size is `4105` bytes, because the image contains a lot of Exif data. Use [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) in command line for listing the Exif data: `exiftool test_image.png`. I see the Exif information contains lots of color related definitions (that FFmpeg may not respect). It is probably related to the issue. For removing the Exif data, we may execute `exiftool -all:all= -r test_image.png`. (It's probably not the only issue because you are saying that the issue also applies my PNG image. Sample without exif: [test_image_rgb32.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glpSh.png).

Comment: @Rotem what R value do you read for the bottom right pixel of the original test image & the one that has been passed through the program? Indeed it depends on the user device as I tried reading the pixel values on https://pixspy.com/ and they were all shifted up 4. So the 121 I read on my mac became 125 and the original image showed that 125 -> 129.

Comment: With paint.net I read `125`. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e69J6.png)

Comment: For both images? Make sure to compare both to check if they differ after being passed through the program.

Comment: Yes, for both images, and also when reading with PIL. When I open the original image with GIPM, it informs me that the image has an embedded color profile, and asks me if I want to convert the profile to GIMP built-in sRGB. When I choose to convert the profile, the RGB values are `[129, 102, 234]`. When I open test_image1.png in GIMP the RGB values are `[125, 103, 226]`. Note: The color profile used by Windows is sRGB. In Mac the default color profile may not be sRGB. FFmpeg ignores and removes the embedded color profile, so the colors are different after the first iteration.

Comment: I updated my answer the best I could (considering that I don't have a Mac for testing).